# extraneous underline character(s) in html results

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want to show a image with some text centered vertically to its right; the following does pretty much what I want with one exception.  It produces an underline with firefox or a series of underlines with internet explorer immediately following the image.  What can I do to get rid of those underlines?  I am certain the image does not contain the underlines.

```
<div style="position:relative;left:50px;">
   <a href="FriendsOfBrooklyn.html">
     <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="si_home.jpg" alt="home">
   </a>
   <a style="position:relative;left:50px;"href="FriendsOfBrooklyn.html">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean the *underline* from the `a`-element? You can remove it: `a { text-decoration:none; }`

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use the `style` attribute (unless implemented via javascript after the initial load).

Comment: Thanks "insertyusernamehere"!  That did the trick.

Comment: I know your problem is solved already, but can you explain what you mean by "a series of underlines"? Maybe put up a screenshot? I see only the continuous underline in IE, just like in other browsers. (It's in the wrong place in IE though.)

Comment: Mr Lister:  I don't know what it is.  In Firefox, it shows up as a single short line immediately adjacent to the right side of the image.  In IE, it shows up as a longer line again immediaetly adjacent to the right side of the image. In both cases, its is vertically aligned with the bottom of the text.